# Does DROOLS 2.5 support Guvnor

Tags: drools-guvnor

Does DROOLS 2.5 (legacy version) support any Guvnor version for managing rules ?

Answer (score 0):

To make use of Guvnor, you need the the client runtime to be using the same version of Drools as you have Guvnor. Guvnor has only existed since 5.2 (as far as I can tell), so you will not be able to use version 2.5 with Guvnor.

If you're still using version 2.5 of Drools, then you really need to upgrade.